# Python: Order of output from a set

Tags: python

Below is my code:

```
import heapq

sentences_scores = {'Fruit': 6, 'Apple': 5, 'Vegetables': 3, 'Cabbage': 9, 'Banana': 1}

summary = heapq.nlargest(3, sentences_scores, key = sentences_scores.get)

text = ""
for sentence in summary:
    text = text + sentence + ' '
print(text)
```

I get the output:

```
Cabbage Fruit Apple
```

But i want to get the output:

```
Fruit Apple Cabbage
```

How can i do that?

Comment: @Chris I think he wants to sort by the order in the dictionary

Comment: @U10-Forward-ReinstateMonica Ah i get it. Thx :). So its an `OrderedDict` question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your dictionary is not ordered, so you can't get the same order out; the order literally does not exist. As comments say, use `OrderedDict` instead.

Also, if you are working with fruit, don't name your variable `sentences`. :P

```
import heapq
from collections import OrderedDict

fruit_scores = OrderedDict([('Fruit', 6), ('Apple', 5), ('Vegetables', 3), ('Cabbage', 9), ('Banana', 1)])

best_fruit = heapq.nlargest(3, sentences_scores, key = sentences_scores.get)

best_fruit_scores = OrderedDict((fruit, score)
    for fruit, score in fruit_scores.items() if fruit in best_fruit)
# => OrderedDict([('Fruit', 6), ('Apple', 5), ('Cabbage', 9)])

best_fruit_names = [fruit
    for fruit in fruit_scores if fruit in best_fruit]
# => ['Fruit', 'Apple', 'Cabbage']
```

Answer (score 0):

[nlargest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) returns a sorted list

> Equivalent to: sorted(iterable, key=key, reverse=True)[:n]

To get the list in the original order you can iterate over the dict to find the elements in the results

```
original_order = [key for key in sentences_scores.keys() if key in summary] # ['Fruit', 'Apple', 'Cabbage']
```

Comment: @Amadan Python 3.6 and newer [maintains dict insertion order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537308/5168011).